# Is Ryanair verification fee illegal?

Tags: fees, air-travel

I have received an email from Ryanair asking me to pay a fee months after I booked my flight. As a result, I cannot see the booking or do anything with it in the official Ryanair page.

The flight was booked with eDreams and the message Ryanair sent me was by email. I have screenshot the Ryanair page that has this message:
[image]

- The email is valid and it is not a scam
- The screenshot is from the Ryanair page when I am trying to find my booking using the 6-digit reference
- I have paid for that return flight in November 2021 and the flight is in July

Is there anything legal I can mention to the Ryanair support? Or do I need to contact eDreams instead?

Comment: I would not be surprised if you agreed to all this, and probably more, when you booked the flight.  You may want to go back and read the "fine print" associated with their booking system.

Comment: @jwh20 it’s somewhere in Europe - there are laws against hidden extra charges.

Comment: Verify using facial recognition technology? Why choose that option when passports have alphanumeric IDs?

Comment: @DaleM It's not "hidden" if it's disclosed.

Comment: @DaleM I do not see anything related here: https://www.edreams.co.uk/terms-and-conditions/

Comment: nothing in what you posted mentions not being able to check in.

Comment: That is what I am saying. I cannot find the booking on the Ryanair site and as a result I am not able to check-in. What they are doing is against the rules.

Answer (score 1):

## The fee is for an *additional* service.

Nobody and nothing forces a user to use face-ID. If a user wants to use face-ID, that incurs an extra charge.

Comment: I will not be able to check in if I do not pay and do that. So, indirectly they force you to do that.

Comment: Also the eDreams terms after I paid said "Additional Services: Airlines may charge for additional services such as checked baggage, airport check-in, preferred seating, flight entertainment (if available), food, drink and snacks etc. Any charges for these additional services are not included in the price of your air ticket unless explicitly provided otherwise and must be paid to the airline directly. We are not responsible for any additional costs incurred and advise you to contact the relevant airline to add any additional services and verify charges." which does not include online check-in

Comment: Such as is not a complete list.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The enumerated items after the *such as* is not a complete list if all items that might be charged for. If the airline would charge for a different additional item not from the list, it's still within the clause. Online Check In with facial recognition is in the *such as... **etc***